# use select results in update oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have searched and found many questions similar to mine but none of the solutions work for me.  This is in Oracle, I don't know the version (I only access it through SQL Developer).  I have two tables (irrelevant columns omitted):

```
describe t_points_receipt
Name              Null     Type          
----------------- -------- ------------- 
USER_ID           NOT NULL NUMBER(9)     
PROMOTION_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(9)     
AMOUNT            NOT NULL NUMBER(9,2)   

describe t_user_promotion_points
Name         Null     Type        
------------ -------- ----------- 
USER_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(9)   
PROMOTION_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(9)   
TOTAL_POINTS          NUMBER(9,2)
```

And, I have this query:

```
select user_id, promotion_id, sum(amount) from t_points_receipt
 where promotion_id = 10340 group by user_id, promotion_id;
```

What I would like to do is update t_user_promotion_points with sum(amount) from the results where t_user_promotion_points.user_id = (results).user_id and t_user_promotion_points.promotion_id = (results).promotion_id.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a correlated subquery for the value to set:

```
update t_user_promotion_points p
set total_points = (select sum(amount) from t_points_receipt r where p.user_id = r.user_id and p.promotion_id = r.promotion_id)
where p.promotion_id = 10340;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update t_user_promotion_points p
set total_points = select sum(amount) from t_points_receipt r
on p.user_id = r.user_id 
where r.promotion_id = 10340 and
where t.promotion_id = 10340
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!  But, I get this error:
'    
    Error starting at line 1 in command:
    update t_user_promotion_points p
    set total_points = select sum(amount) from t_points_receipt r
    on p.user_id = r.user_id 
    where r.promotion_id = 10340 and
    where t.promotion_id = 10340
    Error at Command Line:2 Column:19
    Error report:
    SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
    00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:'

Comment: sorry for the formatting above, I tried fix it but it timed out on me.